# How to tell whether function $x^a \mod{b}$ is bijective or not?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, modular-arithmetic

What conditions must integers $a$, $b$ suffice to make $x^a \mod{b}$ a bijective function?

(I brute force tested out two findings, but not sure whether they are correct or not:

1. If $b$ is prime and $a$ is coprime to $b-1$ then $x^a \mod{b}$ is bijective.
2. If $b$ is not prime, $x^a \mod{b}$ is not bijective unless $a = 1$.

Not sure how to prove these two findings mathematically)

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, Kandarin, and welcome to Math.StackExchange.  I think you're right about the case where $b$ is prime ($x \mapsto x^a$ is an automorphism of the multiplicative group), but the composite case is more complicated.  Take a look at $x^3\!\!\!\!\mod 15$.

Comment: The restriction of this map to the group of units is bijective iff $\gcd(a,\phi(b))=1$. I'm not sure about the whole ring.

Comment: About item 2: the map is bijective for $a=3$ and $b=6$ for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\ b\ $ is prime and $\ a\in \mathbb Z\ $, then the function $\ f\ $ defined on $\ \{\,0,1,2, \dots, b-1\,\}$ by $\ f(x) = x^a\ \mathrm{mod}\ b\ $ is indeed bijective if and only if $\ a\ $ is coprime to $\ b-1\ $.  Here's a formal proof.

Since $\ f(0) = 0\ $, and the domain of $\ f\ $ is finite, the bijectivity of $\ f\ $ will follow once it's shown to be one-to-one on the non-zero elements of its domain.  It's well-known that these elements form a cyclic group of order $\ b-1\ $ under multiplication $\ \mathrm{mod}\ b\ $, so if $\ x\ $ and $\ y\ $ are elements of this group with $\ x^a = y^a\ $,  and $\ d\ $ is the order of the group element  $\ x\,y^{-1}\ $, then $\ d\, \vert\, b-1 $ and $\ \left(x\,y^{-1}\right)^a = 1\ $, so $\ d\,\vert\,a\ $ also, and is therefore a common divisor of $\ b-1\ $ and $\ a\ $.  Thus, if $\ a\ $ and $\ b-1\ $ are coprime, it follows that $\ d=1\ $, and $\ x\,y^{-1}=1\ $, or $\ x=y\ $. So in this case, $\ f\ $ is bijective.

On the other hand, if $\ a\ $ and $\ b-1\ $ are not coprime, then they have a common divisor $\ e > 1\ $.  If $\ b-1 = e\,h\ , a = e\,j$, and $\ g\ $ is a generator of the group of units $\ \mathrm{mod}\ b\ $, then $\ x = g^h\ $ is a non-identity element of the group with $\ x^a = g^{hej}=g^{(b-1)j}=1=1^a\ $.  Thus $\ f\left(g^h\right) = f(1)\ $ in this case, and $\ f\ $ cannot be a bijection.

If $\ b\ $ is composite, the question is more complicated, as several comments have indicated. As the next step towards the general case, I would suggest tackling the one where $\ b\ $ is a prime power.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If $b$ is a prime power, or even divisible by $p^2$ for any prime $p$, the map cannot be bijective for $a\gt 1$:  Let $x = b/p$, then $x^a$ is divisible by $x^2 = b(b/p^2)$, so $x^a \bmod b  = 0$.  Only squarefree values of $b$ are in question.

Comment: How embarrassing not to have realised that—though I did also have in mind the auxiliary question of when $\ x^a\ $ is a bijection on the group of units of the ring.